# Adding key, value pair to object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, each

I have an object, videos. I wanted to add id of video with its duration on a .each loop in Rails. Something like the following --

```
videos = {}

Products.each do |p, index|
  videos << p.id => p.duration
end
```

To get a sample set result like this --

```
videos = { 1: 2345, 2: 3456, 3: 4567 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `each_with_index` :

```
videos = Hash.new
Products.each_with_index do |p, index|
  videos.merge(p.id => p.duration)
end
```

Comment: ah! forgot to make it each_with_index, but the Hash.new and .merge is what I was looking for. thanks for that!